# React Native packager isn't including a 3rd party library in the bundle

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What's the best way to debug the react-native packager not including a dependency in the output bundle?  What I have:

1. Module is included in `package.json` and appears in my node_modules
2. I'm using typescript, and the compiled js file has the `require('countdown')` line.
3. If I inspect the output bundle, or log the `var countdown = require('countdown')`, I can see that the source for `countdown.js` isn't included in the bundle.
4. If I use webpack to create a web bundle, it works as expected.

Here's the compiled js code which is having issues:

```
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var RX = require("reactxp");
var countdown = require("countdown");
var styles = {
    outerContainer: RX.Styles.createViewStyle({
        flexDirection: "row"
    }),
    innerContainer: RX.Styles.createViewStyle({
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingHorizontal: 5
    })
};
var CountdownTimer = (function (_super) {
    __extends(CountdownTimer, _super);
    function CountdownTimer() {
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        _this._setStateToNow = function () {
            _this.setState({ currentDate: new Date(Date.now()) });
        };
        _this.state = { currentDate: new Date() };
        return _this;
    }
    CountdownTimer.prototype.componentDidMount = function () {
        this.timerId = setInterval(this._setStateToNow, 1000);
    };
    CountdownTimer.prototype.componentWillUnmount = function () {
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    };
    CountdownTimer.prototype.render = function () {
        // THIS LINE FAILS SINCE 'countdown' is {}
        var diff = countdown(this.state.currentDate, this.props.untilDate, CountdownTimer.DIFF_ARGS);

        ....

    };
    CountdownTimer.DIFF_ARGS = countdown.DAYS |
        countdown.HOURS |
        countdown.MINUTES |
        countdown.SECONDS;
    return CountdownTimer;
}(RX.Component));
exports.CountdownTimer = CountdownTimer;
```

The error I'm getting is `Object is not a function`, and logging the var countdown shows it is `{}`, and inspecting the `index.android.bundle` shows that the source code for `countdown.js` isn't included.

I am running the packager with `node ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`

Comment: Kill packager, try to clear and reinstall everything with this command: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build/ModuleCache/* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install`. Then come back here and tell the result.

Comment: Doesn't help, same issue.

Comment: No clue then. Not enough information.

Comment: What kind of information would you like?  It's interesting that requiring a different 3rd party lib, e.g. lodash, does work.  But I'm using the same syntax and setup both libraries the same.  And webpack bundles both libraries correctly, but react-native packager doesn't.

Comment: Don't you have somehow cached package somewhere that lands on your device/simulator?

Comment: I don't think so, since I can add new code around the troublesome line and that is bundled and run as expected.  And I can create a new release bundle to see if the library is included

Comment: have you tried `require('countdown').default` perhaps?